# display:none hover trick on a touchscreen device

Tags: css, user-interface, touch

I am using a CSS hover trick to clean up my interface. Controls will only be shown when the cursor is hovering inside the element. I'm running into an issue when using the interface on a touch screen device. If the control button is not shown `display:none` and I touch where it should be, the event is still triggered for the button.

Try this fiddle both in your browser and on a touchscreen device to see what I mean...
http://jsfiddle.net/6PvCn/2/

On a touchscreen device, touch the red square and the alert should fire, without the button even showing up. I tested this on both the desktop Android Emulator and my real Android 2.3 phone.

The effect I'm going for is for the button to first be shown without firing, even if the user touches where the button "is".

I'd rather use a pure CSS solution before resorting to javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Try `pointer-events: none;` along with `display: none;`

Comment: I've read this is not supported in IE. IE is not much of a concern to me, since people on IE should be on a desktop anyways. But how is the support on Windows phones?

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it on my real device, and it indeed executes the button's action. 
You could maybe try to make the red box an image and change the image to a button by an onclick with Javascript. I would have provided you with some code if I wasn't short on time.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with pure CSS, tapping the button will put the button into hover state and fire the click event. Instead you should fire the button off on active.

Comment: That's too bad. IMO this is a use case that should be handled by CSS.

Comment: A work around, take out the JS onclick, wrap the button in an anchor, hover state show it, trigger the action using the href.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with... http://jsfiddle.net/6PvCn/7/

On an Android touchscreen (don't know about IOS), the `hover` event for the hidden element is not fired if it is not shown. So basically I check to see if the element was `hovered` before it was `clicked`.

In a nutshell

```
$(".hidden").hover(function(e) {
  if(e.type == "mouseenter") $(this).addClass("hovering");
  else                       $(this).removeClass("hovering");
}).click(function(e) {
    if(!$(this).hasClass("hovering") return false;
});
```

The fiddle explains the more complicated situation I had with form elements and dynamically added content. It provides a general solution as opposed to this element specific one.

Comment: I don't particularly like this solution so if anyone has better ideas, let's hear em!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a JS solution for you:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bmYROr

The trick is to prevent the button's click event getting fired for the first time the outer div is getting clicked because on touch devices click event has hover effect.

```
let isTouchDevice = true;
let isHovered = false;

document.getElementById('outer').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (isTouchDevice) {
        if (!isHovered) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
        isHovered = true;
    }
}, true);

document.getElementById('outer').addEventListener('mouseleave', (e) => {
    if (isTouchDevice) {
        isHovered = false;
    }
}, true);

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
    alert("hi");
});
```